# SQL Developer Export Encoding for Excel Date

Tags: excel, datetime, encoding, ssms, oracle-sqldeveloper

Regarding datetime values, **is there an encoding that I can select from

SQL Developer that when I export to Excel it is formatted as `datetime`?**.
I tried **UTF-8** & **UTF8**. What appeared was,
`01/01/85 12:00:00.000000000 AM`
This isn't filterable from the filter drop down in excel.

In Microsoft's SSMS, I could select `ANSI` and the datetimes values would appear fine.
But SQL Developer doesn't seem to have this option (`ANSI`).
Current work around that I do is to extract in Excel the value into another column with the date formulas (date, year, month, day).

### Edit

Exporting as datetime that excel can interpret, oracle can actually do it as well.
But it must be exported as **csv**.
It is the same for Microsoft's SSMS.
The oracle excel export that I was using had results that were in 1 sheet and the sql executed in the another.

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't format the cells when we create the Excel file. You'll need to do that in Excel when you open it.

Comment: Noted. I am able to get the datetimes as datetimes in excel, when exporting as csv. However, I need the "sql query" in the 2nd sheet feature when exporting as excel.

Comment: well, csv doesn't have sheets per se, so i'm not sure how you're going to get that

Comment: Yes. I'm just stating that I'm able to get the datetimes as datetimes in excel when exported as csv.